# I need to mock function, but it doesn't work, How to build unittest without modify src code?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

This is the function that I want to test:

```
@Component
public class DataSourceAttributes {

    ...
    ...

    public AWSSecretDB getAttribsBySecret() throws Exception {
        AbstractConnector abstractConnector = new AWSSecretManagerConnector("secretsmanager." + region + ".amazonaws.com", region);
        GenericManager genericManager = new GenericManager(abstractConnector);
        System.out.println("Generic Manager: " + genericManager);

        AWSSecretDB awsSecretDB;
        try {
            awsSecretDB = genericManager.getSecretModel(secretName, AWSSecretDB.class);
            System.out.println("awsSecretDB: " + awsSecretDB.getEngine()); // It must be mocked
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            throw e;
        }
        return awsSecretDB;
    }
}
```

This is my current unit test:

```
public class DataSourceAttributesTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private DataSourceAttributes dataSourceAttributes;

    @Mock
    private GenericManager genericManagerMock;

    @Test
    public void AWSSecretDBGetAttribsBySecret() throws Exception {

        AWSSecretDB awsSecretDB = new AWSSecretDB();
        awsSecretDB.setEngine("Engine Test");
        awsSecretDB.setDbname("DB Test");
        awsSecretDB.setHost("Host Test");

        when(genericManagerMock.getSecretModel(ArgumentMatchers.any(), ArgumentMatchers.any())).thenReturn(awsSecretDB);
        dataSourceAttributes.getAttribsBySecret();

        // The assert is missing, but it's not important for this question
    }
}
```

I need to mock **genericManager** to control **getSecretModel()** function, but It doesn't work.

When I run my test, the System.out.println (located in getAttribsBySecret) prints the following message evidencing that mock is not working:

```
Generic Manager: co.com.bancolombia.commons.secretsmanager.manager.GenericManager@1349883
```

I know if I use the following code, the mock works great, but I don't want to recode something that it's already working in the src directory:

```
@Component
public class DataSourceAttributes {

    private GenericManager genericManager;  // First change

    public DataSourceAttributes () { // Second cahnge
        AbstractConnector abstractConnector = new AWSSecretManagerConnector("secretsmanager." + region + ".amazonaws.com", region);
        this.genericManager = new GenericManager(abstractConnector);
    }

    public AWSSecretDB getAttribsBySecret() throws Exception {

        System.out.println("Generic Manager: " + genericManager);
        AWSSecretDB awsSecretDB;
        try {
            awsSecretDB = genericManager.getSecretModel(secretName, AWSSecretDB.class);
            System.out.println("awsSecretDB: " + awsSecretDB.getEngine());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            throw e;
        }
        return awsSecretDB;
    }
}
```

When I run my test, the System.out.println (located in getAttribsBySecret) prints:

```
GENERIC MANAGER: genericManagerMock
awsSecretDB: Engine Test
```

How it shows, the mock works great. So, this is my question: how can I use a mock inside a class and avoid to declare a new attribute and a constructor in main code. I ask this because the first code works and I don't want to edit it, I think that is not the filosophy of unit tests.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To use unit tests you need to make your code testable first. And this might require some code changes. There is no way to mock local variables inside methods so you need to either pass those variables as parameters to methods or create properties inside objects and pass mocked objects into constructor.

```
@Component
public class DataSourceAttributes {
  private AbstractConnector abstractConnector;
  private GenericManager genericManager;

  @Autowired // to ask Spring to inject dependencies
  public DataSourceAttributes(AbstractConnector abstractConnector, GenericManager genericManager) {
    this.abstractConnector = abstractConnector;
    this.genericManager = genericManager;
  }

  public AWSSecretDB getAttribsBySecret() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Generic Manager: " + genericManager);

    AWSSecretDB awsSecretDB;
    try {
        awsSecretDB = genericManager.getSecretModel(secretName, AWSSecretDB.class);
        System.out.println("awsSecretDB: " + awsSecretDB.getEngine()); // It must be mocked
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        throw e;
    }
    return awsSecretDB;
 }
}
```

And then in test you create instance of you object passing mocked dependencies into constructor

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the code works, why unit-test it then in the first place?  Or, why perform an activity that can bring up a bug if you are not intending to change the source to fix it?

But, more seriously, you seem to be stuck in the "legacy code dilemma": To modify the code, you'd rather have tests in place.  To get tests in place you have to modify the code.

The escape from this is to start with minimally invasive changes that are just sufficient to create those tests you need.  Since this is a migrational approach, sometimes even dirty tricks are acceptable to overcome the dilemma.  This is discussed in much detail with lots of practical advice by Michael Feathers in "Working Effectively with Legacy Code".

In languages with introspection like Java, sometimes introspection can be a solution along the way towards a better testable solution.  That, however, falls in the category of dirty tricks and except for serving as a way to migrate to a better solution, however, I don't consider it advisable.